# Control resolution of Temporal Controller output

Tags: resolution, temporal-controller

I put  QGIS Zurich 3.18 .png files into movie software. (Pinnacle Studio 20). One .png file produced by Print Layout reads fine , other produced by Temporal Controller is illegible, too fuzzy. How do you change the resolution output from Temporal Controller? Yes, I can adjust the output format by adjusting the px sizing.

[image: high resolution]

[image: low resoultion]